# which bibliographystyle would be adequate for LNAI?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

For my bibliographystyle within a paper, `splncs` was used:

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs}
```

An editor sent me:    `the references are not in LNAI style`

Subsequently, I already merged the cites.

For instance:

`\cite{A0,B0}` instead of `\cite{A0} \cite{B0}`

Does `splncs` style matters for LNAI?

Comment: Where did you get the splncs style from? It is not in my installation of TeX Live. What is LNAI style? If you want people to help, you need to either give them *some* idea of what you're talking about or be prepared to wait until somebody happens along who already knows. To put this another way: we all, I think, very easily come to think that our terminology is common knowledge and need to remember it is not!

Comment: got splncs by Springer (a global publishing company). ur question was my question --- which style should be used? (LNAI = Lecture Notes in Artificial Intelligence) another bst file (splncs03) is available. this question could be solved by another lnai author who wrote his/her paper with latex. i asked cause an answer by the conference editors is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [springer docs](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0), the cite commands were divided (which was suitable for my case --- 2 discontinuous numbers --- [7], [11]).

```
\cite{A0}, \cite{B0}
```

as bibstyle, `splncs03` was used.